# trigger reflow but element value not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```js
function countString(str, letter) {
    let count = 0;

    // looping through the items
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        // check if the character is at that position
        if (str.charAt(i) == letter) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
function reflow(elt){
    console.log(elt.offsetHeight);
}
(() => {
 var clickedOnNumber = false;
 var qtyStars =0;
    var Connection = (url, handlers) => {
        offline()
        var ws
        var autoRetry = Timer(() => {
            console.log('connection timeout')
            ws.close()
            start()
        }, 5000)
        var keepAlive = Timer(() => {
            console.log('connection lost')
            offline()
            start()
        }, 5000)
        function isConnected() {
            return ws && ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN
        }
        function online() {
            handlers.onOnline && handlers.onOnline()
        }
        function offline() {
            handlers.onOffline && handlers.onOffline()
        }
        function message(data) {
            handlers.onMessage && handlers.onMessage(data)
        }
        function start() {
            if (isConnected()) {
                console.log('already connected')
            } else {
                console.log('establishing connection')
                ws = new WebSocket(url)
                autoRetry.start()
                ws.onopen = () => {
                    console.log('connection established')
                    autoRetry.stop()
                    keepAlive.start()
                    online()
                    send('?') // request current status
                }
                ws.onerror = err => {
                    console.log('connection error', err)
                    autoRetry.restart()
                }
                ws.onclose = () => {
                    console.log('connection closed')
                    offline()
                }
                ws.onmessage = evt => {
                    keepAlive.restart()
                    message(evt.data)
                }
            }
        }
        function stop() {
            if (isConnected()) {
                console.log('closing connection')
                keepAlive.stop()
                ws.close()
                offline()
            } else {
                console.log('already disconnected')
            }
        }
        function send(msg) {
            ws.send(msg)
        }
        return {
            start: start,
            stop: stop,
            send: send
        }
    }

    const Timer = (callback, timeout) => {
        let timer
        const start = () => {
            if (!timer) {
                timer = setTimeout(callback, timeout)
            }
        }
        const stop = () => {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer)
                timer = null
            }
        }
        const restart = () => {
            stop()
            start()
        }
        return {
            start: start,
            stop: stop,
            restart: restart
        }
    }

    const Lcd = callback => {
    // https://dawes.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/hd44780-instruction-set/
        var display
        var pos
        var cmd = false
        var cursor = false
        var timer
        const show = () => {
            callback(display)
        }
        const write = char => {
            if (char >= ' ') {
                var row, col
                if (pos < 16) {
                    row = 0
                    col = pos
                } else {
                    row = 1
                    col = pos - 64
                }
                var previousChar = display[row].substr(col, 1)
                display[row] = display[row].substr(0, col) + char + display[row].substr(col + 1)
                return previousChar
            }
        }
        const advance = () => {
            pos++
        }
        const start = () => {
            var cursorChar = '_'
            if (cursor) {
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    cursorChar = write(cursorChar)
                    show()
                }, 400)
            }
        }
        const stop = () => {
            if (timer) {
                clearInterval(timer)
            }
        }
        const refresh = () => {
            stop()
            show()
            start()
        }
        const offline = () => {
            display = ['Connecting...   ', '                ']
            show()
        }
        const reset = () => {
            display = ['                ', '                ']
            pos = 0
            refresh()
        }
        const ingest = data => {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var char = data.charCodeAt(i)
                if (cmd) {
                    if (char >= 0x80) { // set position
                        pos = char - 0x80
                    } else {
                        console.log('unknown command: ', char.toString(16))
                    }
                    cmd = false
                } else {
                    switch (char) {
                    // case 0x03: // unknown
                    //   break;
                    case 0x04: // command
                        cmd = true; break
                    case 0x05: // hide cursor
                        cursor = false; break
                    case 0x06: // show cursor
                        cursor = true; break
                    case 0x07: // cursor right
                        pos++; break
                    case 0x0a: // newline
                        pos = 64; break
                    case 0x0c: // clear
                        reset(); break
                        // case 0x0d: // unknown
                        //   break;
                        // case 0x10: // unknown
                        //   break;
                        // case 0x16: // unknown
                        //   break;
                    default:
                        if (char >= 0x20 && char <= 0x7f) {
                          
                            if(data.charAt(i) =='*' && countString(document.getElementById('row1').innerText,'*') < qtyStars)
                            { 
                                 alert(document.getElementById('row1').innerText);
                                write(data.charAt(i))
                                advance()
                            (document.getElementById('row1'))
                            }
                            else{
                                
                            write(data.charAt(i))
                            advance()
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('unprintable character: ', char.toString(16))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            refresh()
        }
        reset()
        return {
            offline: offline,
            ingest: ingest,
            reset: reset
        }
    }

    const Led = (attr, values) => {
        const length = values.length
        return {
            ingest: data => {
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var led = values.charAt(i)
                    $('[' + attr + '~="' + led + '"]').toggleClass('active', data.indexOf(led) !== -1)
                }
            },
            reset: () => {
                $('[' + attr + ']').removeClass('active')
            }
        }
    }

    const Auto = attr => {
        return {
            ingest: data => {
                const hour = parseInt(data)
                const time = hour === -1
                    ? 'OFF'
                    : `${hour < 10 ? '0' : ''}${hour}:00`
                $('[' + attr + ']').html(time)
            }
        }
    }

    const Days = () => {
        const weekDays = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT']
        return {
            ingest: data => {
                const days = data
                for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    if (days.charAt(i) === '1') {
                        $('#' + weekDays[i]).removeClass('inactive')
                    } else {
                        $('#' + weekDays[i]).addClass('inactive')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const Air = callback => {
        return {
            ingest: data => {
                const [temperature, relativeHumidity, tvoc, co2] = data.split(':')
                callback({
                    temperature: parseFloat(temperature).toFixed(1),
                    relativeHumidity: parseFloat(relativeHumidity).toFixed(1),
                    tvoc: parseInt(tvoc),
                    co2: parseInt(co2)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    $(() => {
        var lcd = Lcd(rows => {
            $('#row0', '.lcd').html(rows[0])
            $('#row1', '.lcd').html(rows[1])
            
        })

        var air = Air(({temperature, relativeHumidity, tvoc, co2}) => {
            $('#temperature').html(temperature)
            $('#relativeHumidity').html(relativeHumidity)
            $('#tvoc').html(tvoc)
            $('#co2').html(co2)
        })

        var keypadLed = Led('data-keypad', '12345678UTSP')
        var panelLed = Led('data-panel', 'SAIP')
        var autoArm = Auto('data-autoarm')
        var autoDisarm = Auto('data-autodisarm')
        var days = Days()

        var url = location.protocol === 'https:' ?
            'wss://' + location.hostname + ':8443' :
            'ws://' + location.hostname + ':8443'

        var connection = Connection(url, {
            onMessage: msg => {
                if (msg) {
                    $('.lcd').removeClass('lost')
                    var type = msg.substring(0, 3)
                    var data = msg.substring(4)
                    switch (type) {
                    case '+': // heartbeat
                        $('.lcd').addClass('heartbeat')
                        setTimeout(() => $('.lcd').removeClass('heartbeat'), 100)
                        break
                    case 'SIG': // panel signals
                        $('body').toggleClass('active', /[IP]/.test(data))
                        panelLed.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'LED': // keypad messages
                        keypadLed.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'LCD': // LCD messages
                        lcd.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'AIR': // sensors
                        air.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'ARM': // auto arm
                        autoArm.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'DIS': // auto disarm
                        autoDisarm.ingest(data)
                        break
                    case 'DAY': // auto arm/disarm days
                        days.ingest(data)
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
            },
            onOnline: () => {
                lcd.reset()
            },
            onOffline: () => {
                panelLed.reset()
                keypadLed.reset()
                lcd.offline()
            }
        })

        // bind click commands
        $('[data-click]').click(e => {
            if($.isNumeric($(e.target).data('click'))){
                qtyStars++;
            }
            connection.send($(e.target).data('click'))
        })

        // bind dbl-click commands
        $('[data-dblclick]').dblclick(e => {
            connection.send($(e.target).data('dblclick'))
        })

        // connect/disconnect based on page visibility
        // $(document).on({
        //     show: connection.start,
        //     hide: connection.stop
        // })

        $('.lcd').on('click', () => {
            $('.keyboard').toggle()
            $('.auto').toggle()
        })
        // $('.auto').on('click', () => $('.auto').hide())

        connection.start()
    })

})()
```

so this is part of a WebSocket implementation. The idea is am hacking a web interface to control some electronics which controls an alarm panel.

when you use the keypad, you can type into element row1. When you click on a number on the keypad, it gets sent off to the backend to control a burgular alarm panel. Then row1 gets updated with an asterisk. One asterisk per digit.

However the alarm panel sends multiple messages to update its own display. Dont ask me why stupid in my opinion. Therefore I need logic to ignore the extra messages so I dont get many many asterisks per key press.

The logic doesn't work because the dom is Asyncronous. The first time it runs the value of `$('#row1').val()` is empty which is correct. but the second web socket message comes along and it's still an empty string so i get infinite number of asterisks until the alarm panel times out then updates the display to the current date and time.

As you can see I tried to do a reflow but the value of row1 apparently doesn't get updated.

Is what am trying to archieve even possible? I am using latest version of Firefox but wud like it to be cross browser compatible if possible.

Comment: How are you triggering this? You shouldn't use a loop, use an event listener that runs when the user types into `row1`.

Comment: I am using the the onMessage event handler of the WebSocket client. The qtyStars is incrmented each time you click on a number on the keypad.  But I can't get Val() command to update the value

Comment: The `reflow()` function doesn't do anything except log a message, what does it have to do with rendering the display? The display should render automatically whenever the JS returns to the main event loop.

Comment: Where is it supposed to be updating the input value? `.val()` with no arguments reads the value, `.val(newvalue)` changes the value.

Comment: i got the reflow function from another post on here. It said accessing that property causes the browser to redraw the page.

Comment: Note that "reflow" is not the same as "repaint". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736185/when-exactly-does-the-browser-repaint-and-reflow

Comment: Even if it does redraw, you haven't changed anything in the DOM.

Comment: Unless that's what the `write()` function does?